# Xamarin Share Class Library with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I want to share my class library that I use in my WebApi project which pretty much only contains the entities I am using for data operations and request response models. I've tried adding this to my Xamarin solution which looks fine but I am not sure if I will run into problems if I try to use these entities etc. in the future referenced from this project. Is this a good practice at all? Should I avoid doing so? (It is a .net framework class library, not a PCL) - env is vs2017 xamarin.forms.

Comment: as long as the library is compatible with both frameworks you should be fine.  Code sharing is generally a good practice, and one of the benefits of using Xamarin for mobile.